# "No valid url specified" when trying to install Kibana's Sense plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to install the Sense plugin as specified in ElasticSearch getting started guide, like this:

```
./bin/kibana plugin --install elastic/sense
```

However that command seems outdated and the only one that seems possible is this:

```
./bin/kibana-plugin install elastic/sense
```

But it doesn't work:

```
Attempting to transfer from elastic/sense
Attempting to transfer from https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana-plugins/elastic/sense/elastic/sense-5.0.1.zip
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "No valid url specified."
```

I tried to install it by downloading it locally from here: https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/sense/sense-2.0.0-beta7.tar.gz

And then running:

```
./bin/kibana-plugin install file:<PATH_TO_sense-2.0.0-beta7.tar>
```

But I get this error:

```
Attempting to transfer from file:/Users/raquelalegre/workspace/ORACC/p4-search-tool/kibana-5.0.1-darwin-x86_64/sense-2.0.0-beta7.tar
Transferring 6363648 bytes....................
Transfer complete
Retrieving metadata from plugin archive
Error: Could not find the End of Central Directory Record
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Error retrieving metadata from plugin archive"
```

I'm stuck and can't find how to install this :( Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems that Sense plugin isn’t necessary because Kibana (for sure 5.0.1) is shipped with console available from DevTools menu.

If Kibana is installed locally open http://localhost:5601 and choose “DevTools” from the left menu.

Comment: more specific at http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console (tried with Kibana 5.6.4 and 5.2.1 too)

Comment: Same issue with Canvas and Markdown plugins, actually no need to install them.

Answer (score 1):

```
bin/kibana plugin --install sense --url file:///<path of sense plugin>/sense-2.0.0-beta7.tar.gz
```

Above command works for me with out issues.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, when you are installing locally by downloading complete file was not downloaded.
plz check on that.

Answer (score 0):

The second floor is correct .
I also have this problem. There are many huge differents among different versions .    Under the version 5.4.1  even the

```
kibana plugin --install elastic/sense
```

is deprecated.

If you want install a plugin for kibana, need use the following command

```
./bin/kibana-plugin  install  "plugin name "
```

And the sense plugin has integrated in kibana dev tools